# Laravel package Google Analytics

Tags: laravel, google-analytics

I tried to connect this package and I follow all the steps
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#how-to-obtain-the-credentials-to-communicate-with-google-analytics

I keep getting this error:

Google_Service_Exception
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "errors": [ { "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions" } ] } }

I use the Account Settings / Account Id
my account id have 9 number no letters

Comment: The error seems clear - the user you attempted this with doesn't have enough permissions.

Comment: I added everything: edit, collaborate, read & analyze

Comment: Have you follower the part about granting permissions to your Analytics property? The reason should be there

Answer (score 0):

The error talks about Profile not Account, so you need to use View ID instead Account ID.

Comment: still the same thing

Comment: Do you have obtaineid the credentials to communicate with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

On my file analytics.php

```
return [

    /*
     * The view id of which you want to display data.
     */
    'view_id' => env('ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID'),
```

I change the

```
'view_id' => 11111111,
```

I put the direct number

Comment: This implies either you didn't have `ANALYTICS_VIEW_ID=11111111` in your `.env` file, or you needed to run `php artisan config:clear` to clear the config cache.

Answer (score 0):

you need to hit : https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/usersettings then search All website data(XXXXXXXXX) and past it in view ID